# How to update a number in a text file?

Tags: python

I save to a text file how many food has been ordered and I always need to update the number, how do I do that? it always resets it...

I tried this but it dosen't work:

```
skrif_laxamagn=open('laxmagn.txt', 'r');
skrif_laxamagn1=skrif_laxamagn.read();
print(skrif_laxamagn1)
#skrif_laxamagn=skrif_laxamagn;
skrif_laxamagn.close();

#svo haekkum vid toluna.
skrif_laxamagn1 = int(skrif_laxamagn1) + 1

#svo skrifum vid hana.
skrif_laxamagn=open('laxmagn.txt', 'w');
#skrif_laxamagn_filehandle.write(str(matsedillinn_minn.lax_magn));
skrif_laxamagn.write(str(skrif_laxamagn1));
skrif_laxamagn.close();
```

Comment: What do you mean here that it always resets it? Can you tell what kind of output do you expect in the file before and after updating?

Comment: I want the number to always keep growing but when i run the program again its back to 0 @Suparshva

Comment: Your code works for me. Starting at 0, every time I run the program it adds one to it. That is what you require, correct?

Comment: How many digits are in the number? If you don't know in advance, it it delimited in some way that would allow that to be determined?

Comment: I've tried the program from 0 and 9999; it works as expected in both cases.

Comment: I want the number to be saved in a text file then add to the number again, like if i go up to the number 8 it should be saved so the next time i run the program it starts at 8 not 0 @Sithling

Comment: I want the number to be saved in a text file then add to the number again, like if i go up to the number 8 it should be saved so the next time i run the program it starts at 8 not 0 @Prune

Comment: You're probably saving the text file to the C: folder on your computer, but looking for the text file in the directory that you're running your script from.

Comment: @sonduf: in my environments, the program adds 1 to the number and saves the incremented value back into the file.  The next time I run the program, it adds another 1, and so on.  It does not reset to 0.  There is no code to add more than 1 on each execution.

Comment: Maybe this is small part of code of  actual code, the problem might be somewhere else !! Is it so?